# How do I resolve org.apache.http.ssl with AEM?

Tags: java, maven, amazon-web-services, aem

Ultimately, I'm trying to use AWS S3 libraries in Java code to enable server-side S3 uploads with AEM, but I'm running into problems just getting the dependencies installed and/or recognized by AEM. Every time I add a new dependency, five more issues pop up.

In this bundle I'm attempting to build, This is the error I'm seeing:

[image]

The  `instructions` in my `pom.xml` are this:

```
    <instructions>
        <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
        <Export-Package>
            com.amazonaws.HttpMethod,
            com.amazonaws.services.s3.*
        </Export-Package>
        <Embed-Dependency>
            gson,
            aws-java-sdk-s3,
            aws-java-sdk-core,
            aws-java-sdk-kms,
            jackson-core,
            jackson-databind,
            jackson-annotations,
            jackson-dataformat-cbor,
            ion-java,
            httpclient,
            brooklyn-karaf-httpcomponents-extension
        </Embed-Dependency>
    </instructions>
```

I did some googling and found this:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.brooklyn/brooklyn-karaf-httpcomponents-extension/0.11.0-20170403.1534

I thought that this dependency would fix my problem, so I put it into my list of dependencies, but the package still shows up in red.

All of my dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- OSGi Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.felix.scr</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.felix.scr.annotations</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>biz.aQute</groupId>
        <artifactId>bndlib</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.compendium</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Other Dependencies -->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jcr</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcr</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.adobe.aem</groupId>
        <artifactId>aem-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.sling.models.api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.115</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.115</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-kms -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-kms</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.115</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.4</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit-addons</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-addons</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-cbor -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-cbor</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.ion/ion-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.ion</groupId>
        <artifactId>ion-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.brooklyn/brooklyn-karaf-httpcomponents-extension -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.brooklyn</groupId>
        <artifactId>brooklyn-karaf-httpcomponents-extension</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.0-20170403.1534</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Easier option might be to install AWS S3 connector which includes all these files. Then you can change all your dependencies scope to provided without worrying about missing dependencies. This will also ensure thay your package does not create incompatibility woth S3 connectors in future.

Comment: @i.net actually, this bricked my AEM instance shortly after being installed, so maybe it's not such a good idea.

Comment: This might be because of mixed AWS library versions. Try uninstalling your jars (system/console) and install AEM S3 connector on it's own. S3 connector has older version of AWS SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to install AWS dependencies in your AEM instance is to use the official AEM Oak S3 connector which is available from [Adobe's public repository](https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/adobe/granite/com.adobe.granite.oak.s3connector/). This is also assuming that you are not using S3 datastore in your instance otherwise all of these files and Jars would already be there. For the sake of this answer, I'll refer to [v1.4.8](https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/adobe/granite/com.adobe.granite.oak.s3connector/1.4.8/). You can see more details on installing and configuring S3 datastore over [here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/deploy/platform/data-store-config.html#Data%20Store%20Configurations) however, this answer is not focusing on S3 data store configuration, it's just there to provide all the libraries in your instance.

> This approach is recommended as it keeps your AEM instance compatible with Adobe's AEM official hotfixes and service packs which normally use older versions of AWS SDK as compared to ones available from AWS Developer site.

To install the AWS S3 libraries, do the following steps:

1. Download the latest com.adobe.granite.oak.s3connector-.zip from the [repository](https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/adobe/granite/com.adobe.granite.oak.s3connector/).
2. Unpack the zip into a temporary folder.
3. From your temporary folder, copy all the files under `jcr_root/libs/system/install` to `crx-quickstart/install' folder. You should see some folders named as 1,5,15. If you examine these, they contain several jar files including the AWS SDK.
4. **DO NOT** copy the config files as they will setup your AEM instance to connect to S3 data store which is **NOT** what you want at this stage.
5. Start/restart your instance and wait for it to complete.

To verify that you have all the files:

1. Goto /system/console/bundles.
2. Check that `AWS SDK For Java for OSGicom.amazonaws.aws-java-sdk-osgi` is active.
3. Click on this bundle and see all the imports and exports which will include the libraries you need for your code to work.

Following this approach ensures that your existing datastore is preserved and AEM compatible AWS SDK is properly installed in your system.

Answer (score -1):

it is dependency issue with your "httpclient" dependency.. you should try lower version of httpclient.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

use : 4.5.2 or below, and do not use any beta or redhat version

Comment: try below version from 4.5.2, i had faced the same issue. and after that i used below version issue was resolved.

Comment: I've downgraded to 4.4, which is the furthest back I can go until my tests start crashing, and that hasn't fixed the problem