# AuthenticationSupport service missing after installing S3 connector

Tags: java, aem

I installed S3 Connector for AEM (COM.ADOBE.GRANITE.OAK.S3CONNECTOR) through the package share, and now my AEM instance is bricked.

Whenever I go to localhost:4502, I get a page saying:

```
HTTP ERROR: 503

Problem accessing /. Reason:

    AuthenticationSupport service missing. Cannot authenticate request.
```

In the error logs, I see this stack trace:

```
06.04.2017 14:03:24.889 *ERROR* [FelixFrameworkWiring] org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-core [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.blob.datastore.SharedS3DataStore(4368)] The activate method has thrown an exception (javax.jcr.RepositoryException: java.lang.NullPointerException: null value in entry: component.id=null)
javax.jcr.RepositoryException: java.lang.NullPointerException: null value in entry: component.id=null
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.CachingDataStore.init(CachingDataStore.java:383)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.blob.datastore.AbstractDataStoreService.activate(AbstractDataStoreService.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.invokeMethod(BaseMethod.java:222)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.access$500(BaseMethod.java:37)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod$Resolved.invoke(BaseMethod.java:615)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.invoke(BaseMethod.java:499)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.ActivateMethod.invoke(ActivateMethod.java:295)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.createImplementationObject(SingleComponentManager.java:302)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.createComponent(SingleComponentManager.java:113)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.getService(SingleComponentManager.java:866)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.getServiceInternal(SingleComponentManager.java:833)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.activateInternal(AbstractComponentManager.java:724)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.enable(AbstractComponentManager.java:399)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.config.ConfigurableComponentHolder.enableComponents(ConfigurableComponentHolder.java:676)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.BundleComponentActivator.initialEnable(BundleComponentActivator.java:339)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator.loadComponents(Activator.java:360)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator.access$000(Activator.java:53)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator$ScrExtension.start(Activator.java:260)
    at org.apache.felix.utils.extender.AbstractExtender.createExtension(AbstractExtender.java:259)
    at org.apache.felix.utils.extender.AbstractExtender.modifiedBundle(AbstractExtender.java:232)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleTracker.java:482)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleTracker.java:415)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:232)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleTracker.java:444)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.invokeBundleListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:916)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:835)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireBundleEvent(EventDispatcher.java:517)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireBundleEvent(Felix.java:4541)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2172)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix$RefreshHelper.restart(Felix.java:5063)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.refreshPackages(Felix.java:4253)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkWiringImpl.run(FrameworkWiringImpl.java:188)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null value in entry: component.id=null
    at com.google.common.collect.CollectPreconditions.checkEntryNotNull(CollectPreconditions.java:33)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.entryOf(ImmutableMap.java:135)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap$Builder.put(ImmutableMap.java:206)
    at com.google.common.collect.Maps.fromProperties(Maps.java:1187)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.blob.cloud.aws.s3.S3Backend.init(S3Backend.java:212)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.blob.cloud.aws.s3.S3Backend.init(S3Backend.java:132)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.CachingDataStore.init(CachingDataStore.java:285)
    ... 36 common frames omitted
06.04.2017 14:03:24.890 *ERROR* [FelixFrameworkWiring] org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-core [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.blob.datastore.SharedS3DataStore(4368)] Failed creating the component instance; see log for reason
```

How can I fix/prevent this error?

EDIT: I tried installing this package again on another instance I had, and after a short time, this error happened automatically.  The first time I had reset my instance. This time, I just let it sit after installing it, since I had heard to do so from somewhere.

Comment: If you are following steps from https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/deploy/platform/data-store-config.html#Data Store Configurations just follow it up to step 2,i.e. extract content of S3 connector you downloaded and copy everything from jcr_root/libs/system/install ot crx-quickstart/install folder. These should just be 3 folders named like 1, 5 & 15. Do *NOT* configure the S3 data store in the following steps otherwise you will get the above error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the misconfigured S3 connector as per your other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43263479/how-do-i-resolve-org-apache-http-ssl-with-aem/).

Basically, AEM is trying to connect to S3 datastore from the OOTB config which might have been downloaded from the AEM S3 connector in [Adobe's repository](https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/adobe/granite/com.adobe.granite.oak.s3connector/1.4.8/). These entries are blank by default and therefore cause repository startup to fail which is why you get a *missing repository exception* as above. You can fix this by following the instructions from the SO post below (my other answer).

PS: Apologies for late response as I think we are in different time zones otherwise I would have pointed to this issue in advance!

Comment: Hi @Houseman, did this fix your server? I am facing same issue. Removing the configs starts server properly. But adding back the configs breaks the consoles. Well we need config back anyways right? How did you get server working with config as well? Throws same NPE error as above.

Comment: How was your server set up? Share your problem in a separate post with details like config and startup failure from logs and someone will be able to help.